# Where can I find an MSI installer for Clojure that adds a "clj.exe" to PATH?

Tags: windows, clojure, installation

The typical `clj.bat` in most installers isn't compatible with Git Bash (msysGit).

I've tried `chocolatey install clojure`, but it uses `clj.bat`, which Git Bash can't run.

I've tried `chocolatey install leiningen` and the `lein` "Cygwin-compatible" shell script, but Leiningen fails silently or throws a Java error.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to install leiningen on Windows is just to grab the most recent [`lein.bat`](https://raw.github.com/technomancy/leiningen/preview/bin/lein.bat), put it in a folder and put that folder on the `PATH`. Also download [`wget.exe`](http://users.ugent.be/~bpuype/wget/) and put it in the same or some other folder on the path. Then open a new cmd prompt and type `lein`, it will self-install from there.

I've tried Chocolately myself and it didn't work. Installing leiningen isn't more complicated than the steps above though.

Comment: Yes, I did that. I get a silent failure for the master lein.bat, and a different error for develop lein.bat.